# Kinematics Question involving Graphs and Definite Integration (self-answer)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A bead  moves along straight horizontal wire of length $L$, starting from the left end with a velocity $v_0$. It has an deceleration that is proportional to the distance from the right end of the wire.

Find the acceleration (in $\mathrm{m\cdot s^{-2}}$) at the left end of the wire if the bead reaches the right end of the wire with a velocity of $\dfrac{v_0}{2}$.

Given : $v_0 = 5\,\mathrm{m\cdot s^{-1}}$ and $L = 1\,\mathrm{m}$

---

I answered my own question, can anyone verify that it is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "retardation"?... It sound more like an insult than it does like a scientific word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bead can be treated as a particle as its mass won't make a difference in solving this question.

Let the Distance Travelled by the bead from the left end be $(s)$ and the acceleration be $(a)$. Hence according to the question, the acceleration of the bead is directly proportional to $(L - s)$ :
$$a \propto (L - s)$$

As the distance keeps increasing with time until the bead reaches the right end, the retardation keeps decreasing (hence the acceleration keeps increasing) until it finally becomes $0$ at the right end. There is a linear relationship between $(L - s)$ and $a$.

If we consider the initial accleration to be $a_0$, we can plot a rough graph of Acceleration($a$) against Distance Travelled($s$).

[image: Rough Graph of Acceleration against Distance Travelled]

Here, the $y$-axis shows the Acceleration ($a$) and $x$-axis shows the Distance Travelled ($s$).
We can find the equation of the line using the intercept form of line:

$$\dfrac{a}{a_0} + \dfrac{s}{L} = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow a = \dfrac{a_0}{L}\left(L - s\right) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Now we can use the relation $a = v\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dx}$ to find the velocity.
$$a = v\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dx} \implies a\cdot ds = v\cdot dv$$

$$\implies \int_{0}^{L} a\cdot ds = \int_{v_0}^{\frac{v_0}{2}} v\cdot dv$$

$$\implies \int_{0}^{L} \dfrac{a_0}{L}\left(L - s\right)\cdot ds =  \int_{v_0}^{\frac{v_0}{2}} v\cdot dv \tag{from \ref{1}}$$

$$
\implies \left. \dfrac{a_0}{L} \left(L\cdot s - \dfrac{s^2}{2} \right)\right|_{0}^{L} = \left. \dfrac{v^2}{2} \right|_{v_0}^{\frac{v_0}{2}}
$$

Solving this gives:
$$
\dfrac{a_0}{L} \left(L\cdot s - \dfrac{s^2}{2} \right) = \dfrac{\left(v_{0}\right)^{2}}{8} - \dfrac{\left(v_{0}\right)^{2}}{2}
$$

So, when the Distance Travelled is $s = 1 \,\mathrm{m\cdot s^{-2}}$
$$
\dfrac{a_0}{L} \left(L\cdot 1 - \dfrac{1^2}{2} \right) = \dfrac{\left(v_{0}\right)^{2}}{8} - \dfrac{\left(v_{0}\right)^{2}}{2}
$$

$$
\implies \dfrac{a_0}{L} \left(2\cdot L\ - 1 \right) = \dfrac{-3\cdot \left(v_{0}\right)^{2}}{4}
\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Now putting the values $L = 1 \,\mathrm{m}$ and $v_0 = 5 \,\mathrm{m\cdot s^{-1}}$ in \ref{2}:

$$
\dfrac{a_0}{L} \left(2\cdot 1\ - 1 \right) = \dfrac{-3\cdot 5^{2}}{4}
$$

$$\implies a_0 = -18.75 \, \mathrm{m\cdot s^{-2}}$$

Hence, the inital acceleration is $-18.75 \, \mathrm{m\cdot s^{-2}}$.

Comment: I got the same answer.